# What options do I have for a GWT app as regards advertising revenue

Tags: gwt

I am trying to understand how to embed ads in my GWT app. My app will hopefully attract all sorts of users who then select a category they are interested in sport,  music,  science.  I want then to tailor ads based on the category the user has selected or what they register an interest in so as to get better click through percentages. Where is the best place to go to approach this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is something like Google Ajax crawling using hash bangs, you can find relevant info here :

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification